# cordova splashscreen will shows gray color when app from background to foreground

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

My cordova app using cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2

in normaly it will shows fine.

but when my app goto background mode, and then relaunch app

splashscreen shows nothing, and it comes to gray

like this:

[image]

Any idea for this problem?

Or any solution i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys,

i have already find a suitable method to figure out this problem

add the line below in config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
```